# PFUser Must be registered with registerSubclass iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I'm having trouble with accessing a certain function through Parse.com.  When I run a query for a new view I'm getting the 'PFUser class must be registered with RegisterSubclass' error.  Problem is; this is already registered in the app delegate, so I'm not sure what could be causing the problem.

The code in question:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

[userClass registerSubclass];
[PFUser registerSubclass];

[Parse setApplicationId:@"<x>"
              clientKey:@"<x>"];


[PFTwitterUtils initializeWithConsumerKey:@"<x>" consumerSecret:@"<x>"];

[PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebook];



// Override point for customization after application launch.
return YES;
}
```

The error I'm getting:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'The class PFUser must be registered with registerSubclass before using Parse'`

I tried deleting the app off of the simulator and device, quitting xcode, clearing the `derived data` folder, but nothing seems to be working.

Oddly enough; when I comment out the `registerSubclass` sections, the view works, but the rest of them don't, and instead throw the same error.

Any logical reason why this would be?

Answer (score 0):

Try moving [userClass registerSubclass]; and [PFUser registerSubclass]; under [PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebook];

I had an similar issue and it was because I was running parse code before the Parse setApplicationId...

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't take care of the problem.  I've been working with this project for a while now and it's the first time that this has come up.  Quite aggravating

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer.

For some reason, the app didn't like that I created a subclass for `PFUser` and registered it at the same time as I registered the normal `PFUser` class.  I eliminated the class, re-routed all of the functions from the subclass and it works fine now.

Unsure of why it would give me a problem NOW, but that's what fixed the issue for me.

Hopefully someone else can find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

No PFUser registration is required as far as I can tell. Here is the registration code from my working app followed by edited versions of the User class .h and .m files.

```
[User               registerSubclass];
[Client             registerSubclass];
...
[Parse setApplicationId: kParseAppId
              clientKey: kParseClientKey];
```

.h

```
@interface User: PFUser<PFSubclassing>

// Links
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString*  accountLink;
@property (nonatomic)       int        accountState;

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString*  clientLink;
@property (nonatomic)       id         clientLocal;
@property (nonatomic)       int        clientState;

// Fields
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* nameCalled;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* nameFirst;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* nameLast;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* phoneHome;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* phoneMobile;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* phoneWork;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* pwdRecoveryAnswer;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* pwdRecoveryQuestion;

- (NSString*) nameFull;
- (NSString*) nameFullCalled;

+ (Promise*) promise_loginViaEmail: (NSString*) email
                          password: (NSString*) pwd;
@end
```

.m

```
@implementation User

// Links
@dynamic accountLink;
@dynamic accountState;

@dynamic clientLink;
@synthesize clientLocal;
@dynamic clientState;

// Fields
@dynamic nameCalled;
@dynamic nameFirst;
@dynamic nameLast;
@dynamic phoneHome;
@dynamic phoneMobile;
@dynamic phoneWork;
@dynamic pwdRecoveryAnswer;
@dynamic pwdRecoveryQuestion;

- (NSString*) nameFull
...

- (NSString*) nameFullCalled
...

+ (Promise*) promise_loginViaEmail: (NSString*) email
                          password: (NSString*) pwd
...
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you are not doing anything before your applicationDidFinishLaunching in AppDelegate methods are completed. I was getting this error because I was trying to perform a query before those methods were completed.